# Actualizar un campo cada vez que se inserte o se borre un dato una tabla en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Buenas estoy realizando un trigger en oracle que, cada vez que se inserte o se borre una tupla en la tabla empleado se actualice en la tabla jefe, el campo num_empledos_a_cargo.
La tabla empleado contiene los siguientes campos:

- DNI_EMPLEADO
- DNI_JEFE

La tabla jefe contendrá los siguientes campos:

- DNI_JEFE 
 - NUM_EMPLEADOS_A_CARGO

Por lo cual me ha quedado el siguiente código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ACTUALIZAR_NUM_EMPLEADOS AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON EMPLEADO FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   CONT JEFE.NUM_EMPLEADOS_A_CARGO%TYPE;
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING THEN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CONT
      FROM EMPLEADO
      WHERE DNI_JEFE=:NEW.DNI_JEFE
      GROUP BY DNI_JEFE;

      UPDATE JEFE
      SET NUM_EMPLEADOS_A_CARGO=CONT
      WHERE DNI_JEFE=:NEW.DNI_JEFE;
   END IF;

   IF DELETING THEN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CONT
      FROM EMPLEADO
      WHERE DNI_JEFE=:OLD.DNI_JEFE
      GROUP BY DNI_JEFE;

      UPDATE JEFE
      SET NUM_EMPLEADOS_A_CARGO=CONT
      WHERE DNI_JEFE=:OLD.DNI_JEFE;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

El disparador se crea sin ningún tipo de problema pero a la hora de insertar o borrar una tupla salta el error de que estoy mutando la tabla, es probable que sea porque estoy sacando algún dato de la manera equivocada, pero me estoy volviendo loco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier ayuda se agradece.
Gracias.

Comment: detalle solamente (tu pregunta es correcta).. son registros, no tuplas.. no se de donde salen las tuplas... podrias agregar el error completo por favor?

Comment: @gbianchi, ya he actualizado, el nombre de los campos es diferente pero el código es el mismo.

Comment: fijate la diferencia.. el error no dice que estas mutando la tabla, si no que la tabla esta mutando (esta cambiando) eso.. es muy diferente ;)

Comment: El error debe ir como texto.. lo googleaste? si tu query lo unico que hace es un update en otra tabla, despues de un count, porque no usas un after?? total, no te interesa ni la cuenta por cada registro, ni lo que fue pasando en el medio...

Comment: Si lo he googleado y no he encontrado nada. Por ello que he venido a preguntar aquí. No entiendo lo último el after ya lo estoy utilizando.

Comment: [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16182089/73749) hay varias estrategias... lo que te esta diciendo, es que tu trigger es para cada fila.. o sea que va a hacer esto en cada entrada, fila a fila.. no es lo que necesitas... sacale eso...